# Feedburner - Limit items displayed?

Tags: php, rss, feed, yahoo-pipes, feedburner

I want to put a feed (which I do not own) through feedburner. Somewhere along the lines, I want to have it limited to, for example, 10 feed items. The feed usually contains 1,000 items which, is far too many.

I have considered Yahoo! pipes, and that will be my last resort as the yahoo pipes take a while to update with new information. (page is cached for an hour+ before fetching information again, from personal experience).

If there is any better method, or even a tool I have missed within feedburner which can allow me to do this... Would be great, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Maybe I could do something with php, to take first ten items and republish myself to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal consider [the aggregator module](http://www.drupalgardens.com/videos/110716).

For anyone who isn't using Drupal, Yahoo! Pipes might be OK for you if you don't mind the update time. It's pretty easy to setup simple pipes. You'll just need the "trim" function. Have a feed input box, trim, pipe output, and viola.

Attribute to ShawnRisk from #drupal-support